# RoR if statement by datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, if-statement

I have a movies database where there is a column called `filmstatus`, and it has two choices, Upcoming and Released.

To avoid having to change the status every time a movie is released, how would I put the movie release date in an `if` statement?

Say I add a new movie today and it is released on the 29th of July 2013, how would the statement go?

```
if the current date is BEFORE 29th July 2013
  puts "Upcoming"
else (so if its AFTER 29th July 2013)
  puts "Released"
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a `release_date:datetime` column in the `movies` table.
2. Update `release_date` column to the desired date.

To check the status, you can use the following condition:

```
if release_date >= Date.today
  status = "Released"
else
  status = "Upcoming"
end
```